# Grails: how to identify the primary key of a domain?

Tags: postgresql, grails

Using Grails 2.4.3 and postgres, I would need to find out the primary key column(s) of a domain object at runtime.

```
CREATE TABLE article
(
art_number character varying(255) NOT NULL,
desc character varying(255) NOT NULL,
group character varying(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT artikel_pkey PRIMARY KEY (art_number)
)
```

for this example, I would need a piece of code that returns the string "art_number", as it is the primary key of that domain/database table.

any help appreciated,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information can be retrieved from the [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-key-column-usage.html):

```
select column_name
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where table_schema = 'public' -- change here if the table is in a different schema
  and table_name = 'article' -- change here for other tables
order by ordinal_position -- if the PK has more than one column;
```